# Variable Power Supply to ICs

Tags: power, integrated-circuit

I have a question regarding the reliability of a proposed power delivery system:

We have a power mux (TPS2110A) that is currently switching between outputting 3.7V and 5V, depending on whether or not the 5V power source is available at the time (it isn't always). We have a few chips on our board (LED drivers, single-channel load switches) that can take anywhere from 2.7 to 5.5 volts on the supply pin, and in some modes of operation we need 5V of power to said chips. For our purposes, these chips also need to remain on and operational while the board has power. The proposed solution is to power these ICs off of the power mux output, so that they are on with 3.7V at all times, until 5V power is available and necessary to use.

My question is this: Is there any inherent danger to powering ICs from this variable line as long as the voltage range is within the specifications of the datasheet?

As an example, our switch ICs (SLG59M301V) need to be ON before applying power to the switched lines to ensure normal operation. 5V is applied to the switched input as soon as it is available, at which point the power to the chip ALSO needs to be 5V according to the datasheet. Below is a greatly simplified block diagram of the desired setup:

[image]

Please note that while this setup is not ideal and that there are several (better) ways that the end goal could be accomplished, the need is to make an already existing system work with minimal changes.

Thanks in advance for your time and input!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic and/or block diagram.

Comment: @winny diagram added! sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with doing this in theory. In fact, modern CPUs have [dynamic voltage scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_voltage_scaling) which varies voltage depending on CPU load (as well as clock frequency), throughout normal operation. Its particularly prevalent in portable electronics that need to save power as much as possible.

This is a difficult question to answer, because we can't say "Yes it'll be fine in your design" without thorough testing/simulation - but the concept is sound.

Things to watch out:

- Transients - make sure there is plenty of bulk decoupling capacitance
  to smooth out the rising and falling transitions between voltage
  levels. Inductors can make this worse.
- Every condition is anticipated - Although you expect only a small set of conditions, you need to make sure that none of the combinations could cause issues (5V only, 3.7V only, both, none).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I didn't expect any confirmation of our specific design but wondered if this approach was safe in theory, and you answered exactly that! I will move forward with the design and, of course, test it thoroughly. :) cheers!